# how to find all words in a text and convert then into a script or any output

Tags: python, function, find, pyautogui

What i basically want is a script that finds all the words "click()" or other words, and then uses the amount of times it found that specific word and repeat a function (in this case, pyautogui.click()) the amount of times it counted

```
#For Example:
import pyautogui

text = "click()"

def convert_text():
    #script here
    y=None

#and the output would like something like
pyautogui.click()
```

what i estimate it will look like:

```
text = "click()"

def convert():
    a = text.find("click()")
    if a in text:
        pyautogui.click()
```

but the problem with this is that you can only say "click()" once and it will only click once.
referring back to the question; I want it to "find all" words and convert "all words into script"

Comment: I have no idea what "convert them into a script or any output" is supposed to mean. You need to be *specific* to be able to write code to solve problems. Think clearly about *exactly* where the input comes from (a file? the user's input? A web page? Somewhere else?), *exactly* how it looks and *exactly what should happen* (do you want to use `pyautogui` to click somewhere *now*? If so, how do you know where? Or do you want to replace text *within the original context*? Or create a *new file*? If so, is that new file a `.py` file, or just ordinary text, or what?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `count("click()")` to count the number of times it occurs and loop that many times, executing `pyautogui.click()` each time.

```py
text = "click()"

def convert():
    a = text.count("click()")
    for i in range(a):
        pyautogui.click()
```

Comment: yes, this does indeed find all of those words but how can I execute all of them?
because then the "if a in text:" doesnt work

Comment: What do you mean execute? You are not executing words. You are searching for words and executing commands based on them. If you mean you want to convert text to code, you could try using `eval("command()")`

Answer (score 0):

Did u think of `.replace`?
if u want to replace all click() try this:

```
text = "click()"
script = "your script"

def convert(script, text):
    new_script = script.replace(text, "what u want")
    return new_script
```